# Invalid syntax в названии переменной

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math

Tetragon_Side = input()

Square = Tetragon_Side ** 2

Diagonal = math.sqrt((2 * (Tetragon_Side ** 2) )

Perimeter =Tetragon_Side * 4

print(Tetragon_Side)
```

Что здесь не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скобка не закрыта в предыдущей строке

Comment: Благослави тебя господь, не спал ночью вот и не заметил) Спасибо)